# $e^z$ is never zero, where $e=2.718\dots$ and $z$ is a complex number.

Tags: real-analysis

This theorem is from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis (2nd ed.).

I can't understand the reasoning behind the proof. 
[image]

Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: Which part of that do you not understand? Do you know that $e^{z+w}=e^ze^w$ for all $z,w$? Do you know that $e^0=1$?

Comment: $z\neq 0$ iff there exists $w\in\Bbb{C}$ s.t. $zw=1$. It follows from that $\Bbb{C}$ is a field.

Comment: How did Apostol actually define $e^z$, by the way?

Comment: It seems to me that there's a missing piece of reasoning in the proof. It requires that there does not exist a finite value, $z_0$, for which, as $z\to z_0$, $e^z\to\infty$.

Comment: Imagine that $e^z$ is zero and re-read the one-line proof.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to know the following results (from easiest to hardest to prove:)

1. $0\neq 1$.
2. For all $u$, $u\cdot 0 = 0\cdot u =  0$.
3. For all $z$, $z+(-z)=0$.
4. $e^0=1$.
5. For all $z,w$, $e^{z+w}=e^z\cdot e^w$.

Now, assume $e^z=0$.

Then by $(2)$, $0=e^{z}\cdot e^{-z}$.

By $(5)$, we see that $e^z\cdot e^{-z}=e^{z+(-z)}$.

By $(3)$, we see that $z+(-z)=0$ so $e^{z+(-z)}=e^0$.

By $(4)$, we know $e^0=1$. So we have:

$$0=e^{z}\cdot e^{-z} = e^{z+(-z)} = e^{0}= 1$$

But that contradicts $(1)$.

Comment: I guess that (4) could be obtained as a result from some suitable definition of $e^z$. On the other hand, is it not customary to $define$ $a^0=1$ for arbitrary nonzero $a$ in some ring?

Comment: I'm assuming Appostol defines $e^z$ in terms of the power series. It's hard to define $a^{z}$ in general for complex $z$. @AlexandreVandermonde

Comment: I agree. But regardless I would suppose that $z^0$ would be defined to be 1 for any nonzero complex $z$, and in particular, $e^0=1$. Isn't this reasonable?

Comment: No, that's not reasonable. A lot of modern books define $\exp(z)$ instead of $e^z$ as the power series, and then show that $\exp(z)$ is essentially the "right" definition of $e^z$. Part of that is showing that $\exp(0)=1$. Older books define $e^z$ with the power series, which can be confusing, because readers *assume* features of $e^z$ defined this way that actually require proof.

Comment: So what you're saying is that one would have to check that that the power series definition of $e^z$ agrees with the iterated multiplication view of $e^z$ when $z$ happens to be an integer? Fair point.

Answer (score 6):

The product of zero with any number is zero.

Hence, if the product of two numbers is *not* zero, then neither of the numbers could have been zero.

The proof exhibits a pair of numbers, one of which is $e^z$, whose product is $1$ and therefore not zero. Hence $e^z$ cannot have been zero.

Comment: Does this also mean any $a^z$ can't be zero for real $a$? Can we say it for $a$ complex?

Comment: @Tariq yes, any nonzero $a$ I think.

Answer (score 4):

If $e^z=0$, then $0=0\cdot e^{-z}=e^z \cdot e^{-z}=e^{z-z}=e^0=1$, a contradiction.